# How to get fastboot identifier token to unlock bootloader on HTC One M9 where Android is no accessible?

Tags: htc, bootloader-lock

I want to revive an old HTC One M9 rotting in my grandmothers locker for some years. I would like to flash the phone with a custom ROM but unfortunately it is locked,

[image]

so I can't access Android.

However according to the [HTC documentation](https://www.htcdev.com/process) to unlock the boot loader on has to enable developer options in Android settings first:

> you will need to first manually enable OEM unlocking in Developer
> options in order to allow the bootloader to be unlocked and proceed
> with the next steps.

Apparently without doing so it is not possible to get the identifier token which is needed to unlock the bootloader.

```
fastboot oem get_identifier_token
< waiting for any device >
                                                   (bootloader) [KillSwitch] : /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/frp
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] Last Byte is 0X00, disable unlock
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] oem unlock Turn Off!
OKAY [  0.063s]
Finished. Total time: 0.063s
```

Is there any way to unbrick this phone?

## UPDATE:

As suggested in the comments I tried to flash

> the original RUU ROM to restore a proper state

I got it here: https://htcstockrom.com/htc-one-m9

The following steps are suggested:

- Enter: fastboot oem rebootRUU
- Now enter: fastboot flash zip update.zip
- Once the installationis finished, reboot the device.

However `fastboot oem rebootRUU` makes the device humming and blinking but does not lead to a status where I could successfully upload the file ([same problem described here](https://www.android-hilfe.de/forum/htc-one-m9.2098/recovery-kaputt-ruu-mode-im-sack-und-bootloop.870597.html)):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVG4kT-LiQQ&feature=emb_rel_end

I can upload it in normal `download mode` but there I get:

```
FAILED (remote: '9 RU_SECURITY_FAIL zip from usb command in download mode')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Comment: The whole process is well documented by HTC for their devices: https://www.htcdev.com/process

Comment: @Robert I know, I followed the steps but the device is locked, so I can't make the configurations within Android settings, which are required to get an identifier which is needed to unlock the boot loader.

Comment: The problem is not that it is locked but that the installed software has been modified unauthorized. So you first have to flash an original RUU ROM to restore a proper state, then boot the phone and enable OEM unlock.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the good advice! I updated the question...

Answer (score 0):

The MMO TOOL HTC Module has a feature to get token ID.

[image]

You may have to search it by yourself to download it.

Comment: Please explain a little bit about it.